# Is it safe to briefly have a user's password in memory in plain text?

Tags: security, encryption, hash, passwords

Thinking about how big sites usually have you log in, there seems to be a point in time where company servers have your password in memory in plain text. Is this true, and is it safe?

This is something like how most big sites have you log in:

1. Enter password in browser
2. Encrypt password in-browser using asymmetric encryption public key
3. Send password to site
4. Decrypt password using asymmetric encryption private key
5. Hash password using one-way hashing algorithm (and salt)
6. Compare hashed password to similarly hashed password in database
7. If hashes match, successful log in. Otherwise, failed log in.

Look between steps 4 and 5

4. Decrypt password using asymmetric encryption private key

   4.5. Briefly have some variable server-side with plain text password
5. Hash password using one-way hashing algorithm (and salt)

This means that while the whole hashing scheme is to prevent an attacker from gaining access to passwords EVEN IF the server is compromised, a skilled hacker could get at it anyway.

Is there something I missed? More importantly, is there a safer alternative?

Comment: Need any more help with this? If so I'll update my answer.

Comment: @SilverlightFox If you wouldn't mind adding some more information, I'd definitely appreciate it. My real area of focus here is security even on a compromised machine.

Comment: Sure, done. Please let me know if you need anything further.

Comment: @TheEnvironmentalist Afaik. security is about preventing attackers to compromise the server. If they are in, it is only a matter of time before they can read your passwords. You cannot protect memory. All you can do is setting user privileges properly and try to detect the intruders in time. Note this is only my layman impression, probably others know this better.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is "safe" since whatever is in memory is in your server's memory and *should not* be able to be read externally.

Safe is in quotes as everything is relative and the risk level depends on your perceived threat model - i.e. what threats are you trying to defend against?

The much publicised [Heartbleed](http://heartbleed.com/) bug allowed attackers to retrieve items from servers' memory in 64KB chunks. However, the strategy here is to have a vulnerability management (patching process) in place rather than coding round these types of problems.

Regarding encrypting passwords - this is something you should rely on HTTPS for rather than encrypting them on the client in Javascript. When they arrive on your server store and compare them in hashed format using a slow algorithm such as bcrypt, scrypt or pbkdf2. Also use cookies marked with the secure & http only flags, implement a HSTS policy and you should be good to go on the password storage and transmission front.

CERT's advice regarding handling sensitive data in memory [is here](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/MSC18-C.+Be+careful+while+handling+sensitive+data%2C+such+as+passwords%2C+in+program+code).

The parts most relevant to your question are:

- Disable memory dumps.
- Do not store sensitive data beyond its time of use in a program.
- Do not store sensitive data in plaintext (either on disk or in memory).
- If you must store sensitive data, encrypt it first.
- Securely erase sensitive data from disk and memory.

> This means that while the whole hashing scheme is to prevent an
>   attacker from gaining access to passwords EVEN IF the server is
>   compromised, a skilled hacker could get at it anyway.

Remember that having a secure system does not only mean you need to have secure coding practises and secure infrastructure. This is because you can never have 100% security. Part of the puzzle that this would be missing is any form Intrusion Detection/Prevention (IDS/IPS). This takes the view that systems will be compromised at some point, so rather than trying to prevent every conceivable type of attack, you instead detect it, allowing you to take appropriate immediate action. This would cover you in the event that an attacker managed to compromise your system and started to harvest credentials as they arrive during the login process.

Comment: My point is security even when the server has been compromised. If these companies expect perfect server security they wouldn't bother with hashing passwords. In a worst-case scenario, where an attacker has root access to the server, the idea is for the data to be revealed, but the passwords to be safe. If the passwords are at some point stored in plain text, even just in memory, this is no longer the case.

Comment: The difference here is that if a database table containing passwords is stolen by an attacker is that they have the whole thing in one fell swoop. If you've salted and hashed properly then this isn't a big problem as there's time to get users to change their passwords. However, with your situation when your server has been compromised the attacker can only get each password at the time of use. They might be able to do this fairly easily by adding some code to the top of the login handler than sends the username and password to them. The end result is that it is a much slower process for them.

Comment: They are creating noise and they need to be active on your system to continue the attack. In both situations you should rely on detection and monitoring in order to contain the breach. If you have sensitive information on your system you need IDS so you know your system has been compromised and that code has been added to extract passwords. With good monitoring in place and someone to respond to the attack you can prevent the attacker's method for succeeding and shut them down. In summary containing passwords in memory while they are processed does not carry the same risk as insecure storage.

Comment: Well said. As a last point, what do you think of [Mike's idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28524213/is-it-safe-to-briefly-have-a-users-password-in-memory-in-plain-text/28538637#28528331) to hash the password client-side and then hash the hash server side with something stronger, like bcrypt?

Comment: It all depends if it is "worth it" for your system. So here your end goal is to protect user's passwords if they have used the same password on other systems even if your system has been breached? Adding code increases complexity. Complexity tends to reduce security. If you hashed client side you would need to add a salt - because you do not know which user is logging in this would have to be a system wide salt (known as a pepper). Knowing this exists, an attacker could pre-compute rainbow tables for your hashing algorithm.

Comment: Therefore if they breach your system they just run the client-side hashed password through their rainbow table - and then they have the password. In fact all passwords for users that login during their attack. So a lot of complexity and code added to your own system for little benefit - this simply makes it slightly more work for an attacker to get a password from your system which _may_ work on another system the user logs into.

Comment: A few of your new points here seem to contraindicate the behavior in the question. Assuming working with data as program variables qualifies as "storing in memory" (which of course is where variables are stored), _Do not store sensitive data in plaintext (either on disk or in memory)_ and _If you must store sensitive data, encrypt it first_ together imply the process described in the question is insecure on a compromised machine. The underlying goal is to prevent an attacker from passively (without changing the code, which would be noticeable) accessing passwords. Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: @the I'd say storing would be defined as storing it semi permanently - in session for example. Using is not the same as storing, however you may still want to securely erase variables.

Comment: The original question was intended to address security from the attacker's point of view, which tends to be the best point of view for identifying attacks. If I wanted to collect passwords from a service that implements current best security practices, I could collect them either from the client or the server. Attacking massive numbers of client machines isn't practical, and under our assumption of correctly implemented security, the server-side database would only contain salted hashes. The only step in the process in which passwords would be available on the server in plain text is ...

Comment: ... between the decryption of the encrypted password sent by the client and the hashing and salting to compare with the salted hash stored in the server-side database. At that moment (step 4.5 in the original question, if you will) the password would be stored in memory. While parsing memory is rather difficult, this would be the best attack, assuming there is no attackable part of the modern security architecture (no mathematical backdoors, no servers sending out chunks of heartbeat data, etc.). I might then run a process in the background that reads from memory, which I'm trying to prevent.

Comment: @the: I understand the problem - I still maintain the solution to this is to get your system penetration tested and to implement Intrusion Detection so you are aware if security is breached. If the risk you're trying to control is that of your user's passwords that may have been used on other sites then hashing on the client would prevent the password being known server side.You would still need the client to know the salt once the username is known, in order to correctly hash for this user. You need to return a consistent hash value for non existent users otherwise you are vulnerable to...

Comment: @the: [user enumeration](http://bit.ly/1E1yBhf) - so if someone tried to log in with a non-existent user then you need to return the same salt _every time_, otherwise an attacker would know they don't exist. As the attacker can get this salt, they will be able to go ahead and generate rainbow tables for every user in advance. Then your persistent attacker could then compare the hash sent to your system to their tables to grab the password that way. Also note that if an attacker can read memory, they must have control of your machine in some way. They could simply change the code served to each

Comment: @the: client and change the JavaScript that hashes into JavaScript that just sends plain text. So you've increased complexity, yet the attacker has just changed tack and has managed to circumvent your defense instantly. I think an attacker than can only read memory is an imaginary threat - an attacker that has got that far will go the extra mile to defeat any hashing protections you put in place. Your approach might work - in which case go ahead - but you've got your work cut out simply to protect users that reuse passwords. Even [Google](http://bit.ly/1It7iEx) get it wrong...

Comment: @the: attempting to improve security by adding code.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct. The remote attacker would have to change the code though. This can be easily done for PHP, but not so for compiled languages. Obfuscated PHP code also has a place in hindering the attacker in their endeavor.

Sometimes even compiled or obfuscated code cannot stop the attack when the attacker is one of the developers.

Note that multi-party communication and zero-knowledge proofs can be probably subverted in the same way when used for user authentication. I don't think there is really an alternative besides making it really hard for the attacker to break into your server.

Answer (score 1):

> This is something like how most big sites have you log in

Actually, I have never seen any sites encrypt the password client-side. Encrypting on the client and then decrypting it on the server gains absolutely nothing. That's what SSL certificates are for. Almost all sites I've ever seen in my life just send the password in plain text to the server and then hash it there (we hope).

If you are trying to prevent the server from ever having the plain text password in memory, you could hash it client-side and then hash the hash on the server. Just keep in mind that when you hash a password on the client, the hash actually becomes the password.

Comment: _Just keep in mind that when you hash a password on the client, the hash actually becomes the password._ I realize that. My first thought was hash the hash, my second thought was are there any security disadvantages to that... As soon as you play the 'what if an attacker gains control of a server, how do you ensure security then' game, you're best off setting aside a bottle of aspirin.

Comment: I think you have to think first about what you are actually trying to prevent. If you are trying to prevent a hacker who has somehow compromised the server from gaining access to someone's account, well... you already have bigger problems to worry about, and if your server is compromised, they already have access to whatever accounts they want. If that's the case, send the password in plain text anyway. The *only* useful thing that I can think about for hashing client-side is to prevent the users from using the same password in multiple places so if your server were compromised, this

Comment: wouldn't leak out your users' bank/PayPal/ebay/facebook passwords since most people use the same password everywhere. Of course, you wouldn't be able to use a salt per user because the user would also have to supply this salt with the hash, which they wouldn't know. So your system would still be vulnerable to rainbow tables.

Comment: My advice is to just harden the server as much as possible. Disable all unnecessary services, disable telnet and ftp, enable SSH with public key authentication, don't allow any logins over an insecure connection over any protocol (even HTTP), store passwords with a secure hash (e.g. bcrypt) and you should be fine. You may also want to look into two-factor authentication for your application. It is relatively easy to set up something like Google Authenticator. This should improve the security of your web app greatly.